# Where are the Canon MF8080cw wireless drivers?

Tags: printing, software-installation, canon

I recently bought Canon MF8080cw wireless printer and scanner
but I am unable to find the drivers for it, I am using ubuntu 13.10 x64

Answer (score 0):

please check canon official website [here](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/printers_multifunction/color_laser_multifunction/color_imageclass_mf8080cw#DriversAndSoftware) . 
[image]